# Where can I ask about networking homework/assignments?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope, homework

Where can I ask about networking homework/assignments? I've been told it's off-topic in [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

I can't seem to find the appropriate place to ask [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/50234/31801), and similar questions did not ask about homework-related questions.

Comment: Were you just needing clarification on some part of your homework question that you've already put your own effort/research into, or were you planning on posting your assignment and asking for someone to come up with the solution?

Comment: the first option :) this is the "problematic" post: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50234/expressing-the-throughput-of-channels-managed-with-slotted-aloha-and-basic-bit-m?noredirect=1#comment85199_50234

Comment: why do you need to? cant you rephrase questions to be generic enough to be of value to others, but small enough to be answerable? and if you cant, it's unlikely we can help any more than your instructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking a 'theoretical' question on a site which is more focused on ['practical' questions](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Instead, your question leans more towards [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), which already has some questions about [ALOHA](https://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=aloha). Whether your question is currently in the right form to ask there, I don't know. It's probably OK, but it doesn't hurt to ask a regular from that site, e.g. in [their main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2710/computer-science).